# confused with buffered reader in java

Tags: java

1. when i run the code only with //1 - start, the output is ascii value of input character
2. when i run the code only with //2 - start, the output is the entered string terminated by newline character
3. when i run the code with both (as shown in below code), only //1 - start executes, readLine() is being considered in a strange way.
4. when i run the code with both (with //2 - start placed above //1 - start), both the codes executes fine,

Please explain why this strange behavior happens in case 3 but not in case 4.

```
public class InputBufferedReader {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try {
        //1-start
        //read one character
        System.out.println("enter input: ");
        int b= br.read();
        System.out.println(b);
        //end

        //2-start
        //read a string
        System.out.println("enter input string: ");
        String a = br.readLine();
        System.out.println(a);
        //end
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by " readLine() is being considered in a strange way" ?

Comment: My guess, readline returns an empty line.

Comment: @Gaël readLine() breaks without waiting for anyinputs,

Comment: @david ya, maybe newline, because it just terminates without accepting any inputs, but why

Comment: it reads an empty line because read does not remove the newline from the first input

Comment: It may be more clear if you add the actual input and outputs to the question. Have you tried running it with an input that is more than one character long?

Comment: @david ty, i gave input: a b, output is 97 and spaceb (from readline()). you are right

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: david's answer is helpful. thanks @david

Comment: @david how to make it work normally? read() followed by readLine().

Comment: @david shooting a blank readline() inbetween read() and readLine() is a solution i saw

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `BufferedReader` uses the `InputStreamReader` with `System.in`. The `BufferedReader` uses the `read()` method from `InputStreamReader` to read the data from the standard input stream `System.in`. Now lets look into the API for this `read()` method.

> [...] This method blocks until input data is available, the end of the stream is detected, or an exception is thrown.

Blocking means in this context waits for user to input data throu the console confirming with the Enter Key.
With that in mind lets examine your cases.
**1.** `int b= br.read();` Nothing is already typed, so this method blocks until user typed something and then prints the ascci value of first character.
**2.** `String a = br.readLine();`  Nothing is already typed, so this method blocks until user typed something and then prints the whole line.
**3.**

```
int b= br.read();
```

Lets image user typed  `a`  confirming with Enter Key that means the input is `a\n`. Now `read()` reads the first character which is `a`.

```
String a = br.readLine();
```

This `read()` call will not block and ask for user input because there is unconsumed input left `\n`. So `readLine()` will read `\n`.
**4.**

```
String a = br.readLine();
```

User is asked for input which is confirmed with Enter Key. And the whole line will be read.

```
int b= br.read();
```

There are no unconsumed data left, because `readLine()` already has read the whole line including `\n` character. So this `read()` call blocks and user is asked for input.

Answer (score 1):

**int read()** method attempts to Read Next Character from the Console(or File) and Return its **Unicode Value**,

As this Method Returns Unicode Value Compulsory at the Time of Printing we- should perform type- Casting.

If there is No Next Character the we will get **-1**.

**String readLine()** Method attempts to Read Next Line from Console(or File) and Returns it, if it is available.

If the Next line is Not available, then return null.

Comment: thank you for the answer,but  i think @David's comment was more helpful for me